# GameScene misses initializers

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I get an error that "Class 'GameScene' has no initializers" when I try to add a level selection to my game.

I present the scene in GameViewController.swift like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.level(1) {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.showsPhysics = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

And in my GameScene.swift I wanted to handle the level selection like this (got this from Ray Wenderlich iOS Game Development Books)

```
    class func level(levelNum: Int) -> GameScene? {
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "Level\(levelNum)")!
    scene.currentLevel = levelNum
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    return scene
}
```

But then I get the error as I mentioned and I dont know how to fix this issue :-? Are there any other ways to make a level selection? Currently I have for each level one sks file, which is something I find really handy, since I enables me to lay out the levels visually.

Any recommendations and/or help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add code for GameScene?

Comment: You already posted the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238442/game-scene-cannot-be-constructed-because-it-has-not-accessible-initializers